# GAE - How to configure access to Cloud SQL from Google App Engine in quarkus java11 app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'am evaluating a Quarkus application on App Engine.
The application needs a Postgres DB on Cloud SQL, where I named the instance 'quarkus'.

But I'am stuck getting these access error:
Not authorized to access instance: addlogic-foodiefnf-1:quarkus

The serviceAccount:addlogic-foodiefnf-1@appspot.gserviceaccount.com has these roles:
Cloud SQL Admin
Cloud SQL Service Agent
Editor

What I'am missing?

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 7,
      "message": "Not authorized to access instance: addlogic-foodiefnf-1:quarkus "
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "addlogic-foodiefnf-1@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "serviceAccountDelegationInfo": [
        {
          "firstPartyPrincipal": {
            "principalEmail": "app-engine-appserver@prod.google.com"
          }
        }
      ],
      "principalSubject": "serviceAccount:addlogic-foodiefnf-1@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "107.178.230.54",
      "requestAttributes": {
        "time": "2021-09-27T06:18:33.283490Z",
        "auth": {}
      },
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudsql.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "cloudsql.instances.connect",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "instances/quarkus ",
        "permission": "cloudsql.instances.connect",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {
          "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com",
          "name": "projects/addlogic-foodiefnf-1/instances/quarkus ",
          "type": "sqladmin.googleapis.com/Instance"
        }
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "instances/quarkus ",
    "request": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlInstancesCreateEphemeralCertRequest",
      "instance": "europe-west3~quarkus ",
      "project": "addlogic-foodiefnf-1",
      "body": {}
    },
    "response": {}
  },
  "insertId": "-il5zyxe1b1rn",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloudsql_database",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "addlogic-foodiefnf-1",
      "database_id": "addlogic-foodiefnf-1:quarkus ",
      "region": "europe-west3"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-09-27T06:18:33.270158Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/addlogic-foodiefnf-1/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-09-27T06:18:33.799357464Z"
}
```

Background story:
I've set up my quarkus application regarding to
https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-google-cloud
but class 'PostgreSQL10Dialect'failed to load:
See [Why is class PostgreSQL10Dialect not found on Quarkus in Google App Engine java11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350157/why-is-class-postgresql10dialect-not-found-on-quarkus-in-google-app-engine-java1)

At this current post here I like to learn how to debug the access error at Google App Engine to Cloud SQL.
Cloud SQL instance is set up with public IP. Is there anymore setup needed at Cloud SQL instance?
As said above, service account at standard app engine has role 'Cloud SQL Admin' as required by
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard#java

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the postgres-socket-factory dependency and configure cloud SQL with addotional JDBC params as described here: https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-google-cloud#using-cloud-sql

Comment: Yes, postgres-socket-factory is provided and addotional JDBC params are present.
I get issues sorted out, I editet this issue to get focus on the connection/access error and put the background story in a separate post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350157/why-is-class-postgresql10dialect-not-found-on-quarkus-in-google-app-engine-java1

Comment: A few quick things to check: are the Cloud SQL instance and the App Engine service in the same project? What are you setting for `CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME`? Have you double checked your username and password?

Comment: Yes, Cloud SQL instance and the AE are in the same project.

I double checked user+password - login to Cloud SQL is fine from the Cloud Shell.

CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME is set via Quarkus application.properties:
´´´
cloudSqlInstance=addlogic-foodiefnf-1:europe-west3:quarkus
´´´

I now assume hibernate tries to do auto configuration as I used:
´´´
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
´´´
and this fails?

Changing db-kind=other 
shows this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350157/why-is-class-postgresql10dialect-not-found-on-quarkus-in-google-app-engine-java1

Answer (score 0):

I understand that using ´quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql´ triggers hibernate to do auto configuration. And therefore the connection can not be established.

**I have to use `quarkus.datasource.db-kind=other` to prevent Quarkus auto-configuration and access problems.**

(As this solves this question here, my issue at [Why is class PostgreSQL10Dialect not found on Quarkus in Google App Engine java11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350157/why-is-class-postgresql10dialect-not-found-on-quarkus-in-google-app-engine-java1) is still open.)